# Delete row above cell with certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where some cells in Column M have a value of `XYZ`.

How do I delete the row **above** the row where this value is present?

Comment: Half of the related links to the right address your problem...

Answer (score 0):

In Row1 of a spare column put:

```
=M2="XYZ"
```

and copy down to suit. Filter that column to select TRUE and delete what's visible.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I can't see the simplest solution.